# Composition of an analytic function F with an analytic function f in a C* algebra A such that F(f) in A?

Tags: c-star-algebras, function-and-relation-composition

I have a C* algebra A, a function $f(x)\in A$ and an analytic function $F:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$. I would like to know what condition must have $F$ such that $F(f)\in A$.

The idea is the following: F must be analytic on a neighborhood of $Im(f)$ but I've been trying to see how to prove it or some reference about it, but I haven't found nothing...

Comment: When you say $f(x) \in A$, do you mean $f$ is a function mapping some set to $A$, or do you mean $A$ is a $C^*$ algebra of functions and $f \in A$?

Comment: $A$ is a C* algebra of function where $f\in A$.

Comment: $F:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ means $F$ is entire and its Taylor series can be applied without problem. Robert answer is needed when $F$ is analytic on a simply connected open $U\supset \sigma(f)$ but with some singularities away from $U$

Answer (score 1):

You can define a holomorphic functional calculus on any complex Banach algebra with identity.  If $F$ is analytic in a neighbourhood $U$ of the spectrum $\sigma(f)$, take a finite collection of
simple closed contours $\Gamma$ such that every point around which $\Gamma$ has nonzero winding number is in $U$, and $\Gamma$ has winding number $1$ around every point of $\sigma(f)$.  Then define 
$$ F(f) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_\Gamma F(z) (z - f)^{-1} \; dz$$